# Eliminating repeated characters in a string

Tags: java, filter, text-processing

Hello I'm trying to get this piece to work so that when the input is a string such as "aaabbbccdddeef" the output is "abcdef". I know there are  solutions out there but it's bothering me that this isn't working and I can't see why. I'd really appreciate it if someone could give me a hand in understanding why this piece of code doesn't work.

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("please enter the string of characters: " );
    String str = input.nextLine();
    char[] store = new char[str.length()]; 
    int count =0;

    for(int i=0; i<str.length();i++) {

        for (int j=0; j<str.length(); j++) {

                if(str.charAt(i)==store[j] ){
                    count+=1;//when character not stored keep count to offset store position
                    break;
                }else {store[i-count] = str.charAt(i); count = 0;}
            }
        }
    System.out.println(str);
    System.out.print(store);
```

Comment: Thank you @ScaryWombat but any idea on what the hell is wrong with it? cos this has driven me mad for the last few hours T_T

Comment: yes it is a reset to offset the index when not storing a character and it is comparing a to a null, I've tested it by initialising the whole store array with '*' and it still doesn't work.

Comment: If you don't want to use the answers provided here, then I suggest you use a debugger and step through the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to change the logic inside the second `for` loop. you have to iterate `store` not the `str` in the second for loop. Check my solution:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("please enter the string of characters: ");
    String str = input.nextLine();
    char[] store = new char[str.length()];
    int count = 0;
    boolean charInStore = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        charInStore = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < store.length; j++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == store[j]) {
                charInStore = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!charInStore) {
            store[count] = str.charAt(i);
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(str);
    System.out.println(new String(store).trim());
```

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j < store.length; j++) {` store and str are the same length.   But **yes** to the idea of only adding if not found.  Same as my answer using `contains` in a String rather than looping through an Array.

Comment: @ScaryWombat You are right. your answer is more optimized.

Comment: @Anuradha THANK YOU brother thank you so much! you saw what I was trying to do.

I now notice that I was storing at the wrong time, while inside the loop because I needed to use the else of the if statement. 

Using that flag to keep track of the state of the if statement did the trick. 

Also using count as the index as oppose to the offset of the index is more efficient, thanks again!
Now I can sleep!

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to append to a StringBuilder if it does not exist

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("please enter the string of characters: " );
    String str = input.nextLine();
    StringBuilder store = new StringBuilder ();

    for(int i=0; i<str.length();i++) {
        if (!store.toString().contains(Character.toString(str.charAt(i)))) {
            store.append(str.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(str);
    System.out.print(store);
```

Answer (score 1):

You really need to make use of desk checking to get a better understanding of what your code is doing...

```
+------+------+--------+--------------------+-------+
|  i   |  j   |  str   |       store        | count |
+------+------+--------+--------------------+-------+
|    0 |    0 | aaabbb | [a,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ] |     0 |
|    0 |    1 | aaabbb | [a,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ] |     0 |
|    0 |    2 | aaabbb | [a,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ] |     0 |
|    0 |    3 | aaabbb | [a,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ] |     0 |
|    0 |    4 | aaabbb | [a,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ] |     0 |
|    0 |    5 | aaabbb | [a,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ] |     0 |
|    1 |    0 | aaabbb | [a,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ] |     1 |
| --- break                                         |
|    2 |    0 | aaabbb | [a,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ] |     2 |
| --- break                                         |
|    3 |    0 | aaabbb | [a, b,  ,  ,  ,  ] |     0 |
|    3 |    1 | aaabbb | [a, b,  ,  ,  ,  ] |     1 |
| --- break                                         |
|    4 |    0 | aaabbb | [a, b,  , b,  ,  ] |     0 |
|    4 |    1 | aaabbb | [a, b,  , b,  ,  ] |     1 |
| --- break                                         |
|    5 |    0 | aaabbb | [a, b,  , b, b,  ] |     0 |
|    5 |    1 | aaabbb | [a, b,  , b, b,  ] |     1 |
| --- break                                         |
+------+------+--------+--------------------+-------+
```

The core problem is `store[i - count] = str.charAt(i);`.  It might not be obvious until you understand what's going on.

Let's take a closer look at the point things start going wrong...

```
+------+------+--------+--------------------+-------+
|  i   |  j   |  str   |       store        | count |
+------+------+--------+--------------------+-------+
| --- break                                         |
|    3 |    0 | aaabbb | [a, b,  ,  ,  ,  ] |     0 |
|    3 |    1 | aaabbb | [a, b,  ,  ,  ,  ] |     1 |
| --- break                                         |
|    4 |    0 | aaabbb | [a, b,  , b,  ,  ] |     0 |
|    4 |    1 | aaabbb | [a, b,  , b,  ,  ] |     1 |
| --- break                                         |
+------+------+--------+--------------------+-------+
```

Ok, when `i` = `4` and `j` is `0`

- `str.charAt(i)` = `b`
- `store[j]` = `a`
- `count` = `0`

So, `b` != `a`, so you use `store[i - count]`, which equates to `store[4 - 0]` and store `str.charAt(i)` (or `b`) at that point

And things just spiral out of control from there.

The "basic" problem is `count` has no relevance between loops.  I'd also question the need for two loops anyway

Comment: what a Mad answer ;-)

Comment: @ScaryWombat 

Answer (score -1):

This can be a simple solution it can also be a very complex solution.

My solution is very simply in my opinion:
Make a for loop that iterates through the entire length of the string
Then use index of + charAt to determine if a string repeats over 1
Create new String called temp.
Then if so remove every single one of those characters leaving only one
Then print temp

```
String.indexOf('a');
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but the question wasn't about "how" to solve the problem, but "why" the posted solution didn't work